# Rails persisted locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I'm about to start adding I18n support for a Rails app I'm currently working on. In the past I have set the locale value from the URL. I just was wondering how bad practice it'd be to persist the locale?

So instead of something like this:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Do something like

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = current_user.try(:locale) || I18n.default_locale
end
```

It looks like FB persists the locale, what are the trade-offs of this schema? how might this affect SEO stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: What about look for the locale on the user's environment?

Comment: Like in the browser preferences?

Comment: yes, could work too, I guess.

Comment: I don't really like that approach because it breaks one of the first and most fundamental rules of the internet, that is, that a url should link to the same page, for everyone. I really like Zubin's answer though. Also, you may find this [Etsy blog post](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/10/21/localizing-logically-for-a-global-marketplace/) interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've faced these issues and ended up using this strategy:

- locale in URL (allows page caching and direct linking in specific language)
- store locale in user cookie

If locale is not present in URL, try (in order):

- retrieve from cookie
- guess from geolocation
- guess from browser header accept language
- fallback to app default

Hope that helps; let me know if you'd like any points elaborated on.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I think the ability to cache a page for a specific language is important. Depending on the application, that might be a cons of a db or cookie persisted schema. And SEO stuff.

Comment: No worries! One more thing: regarding SEO, ensure you translate your document titles and meta descriptions otherwise Google may penalise for duplicate content.